# How safe to use Python UUID instead of BigQuery GENERATE_UUID() when inserting data?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Adding UUID as an id column to the `DataFrame` and push to BigQuery using to_gbq maintains the uniqueness?

Answer (score 2):

UUID is a [standard format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), there should be no difference between implementations.

However, some [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) of UUIDs (specifically v1, v2) include information about the computer it was generated on (to maintain uniqueness), which will be different based on whether you generate it on a BigQuery server or your application's. This probably won't make a difference though, realistically. (UUIDs v3, v4, v5 will not have this difference)

Answer (score 1):

it is the same - UUID in Python generate such unique Id like UUID in BQ